# How to index 1d array without singleton dimension in python by 1d array with singleton dimension?

Tags: python, indexing

what is the procedure to index variations of 1d arrays in python?

For example, consider the following example:

```
a = np.ones(100)
b = np.ones(100, 1)
a[b > 0]
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-05e3ddce24c9> in <module>()
----> 1 a[b == 1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How would I do this indexing, without creating a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `a` is a 1D array. Singleton dimensions are still dimensions.

Remove the second dimension from `b`:

```
a[b[:, 0] > 0]
```

`b[:, 0]` takes a view of `b`'s data, not a copy.